# Command line refractoring tool for Scala

Tags: scala, refactoring, command-line-interface

I am looking for command-line tool to perform simple refactoring on a Scala code.

The things I suppose to do:

- Renaming classes, objects, traits
- Renaming methods and fields
- Renaming arguments and variables

IDE libraries is OK, if they have a usable CLI interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Scala Refactoring](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-refactoring) as a standalone library.